# Apache Loadbalancer with Pure java application

Tags: java, apache, load-balancing

I hava a pure Java application which publishes a webservice without needing any Application server. How can I configure the Apache Http Loadbalancer to forward requests to servers on which this application is installed.

I can handle it when I deploy an webservice over an Application Server such as Glassfish. But I do not know how to do it with pure Java application.

Comment: Is your app listening on any port ?

Comment: My application is just listening 2020 port for Webservice request. It does not listen 8009 default port of ajp. As far as I know glassfish server instances listen that port so that apache http server can communicate with them. I want to learn how to configure loadbalancer without coding any ajp port listening. Instead loadbalancer can handle status of instance by looking timeout value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use http:// instead of ajp:// in your balancer config, like:

```
<Proxy balancer://myApp>
  BalancerMember http://47.168.96.31:2020 route=r1
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.2:2020 route=r2
</Proxy>
```

or directly forward with proxy like:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://myApp
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myApp
```

Let's say apache is on 47.168.96.31, then you'd access the service as `http://47.168.96.31/StockQuote/StockQuoteService`

If you'd rather have the service respond at `http://47.168.96.31/`, you could do:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://myApp/StockQuote/StockQuoteService
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myApp/StockQuote/StockQuoteService
```

Comment: both applications giving services at. http://47.168.96.31:2020/StockQuote/StockQuoteService  http://192.168.0.2:2020/StockQuote/StockQuoteService  what would be the lates configuration.

Comment: One seems to be external address and the other one is internal/private. Is this correct? Are you trying to balance two routes to the same server?

Comment: I updated the answer to use the two items you've given. However, this will only work on your network since the 192.xxx address is a private network.

Comment: Apache is on 47.168.96.31 and this server is connected to other server (192.168.0.2) via HUB over other ethernet interface. So loadbalancer can reach server having private address. Actually it is not so important.

Comment: I am having the following error. Invalid command '<Proxy', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
httpd not running, trying to start

Comment: It sounds like you may not have mod_proxy installed, which would be required for the above solution. You can find more details on the configuration here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Is it possible if Apache http loadbalancer works at both mode mod_jk and mod_proxy. I need it because same servers have instance of glassfish and giving an other services in additional to that pure java application gives.

Comment: I've never done it, but I am sure you can configure both. You would just need to send the different mount points to the appropriate connector. However, you can also use mod_proxy directly with ajp. You'd just change the http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 to ajp://xx.xx.xx.xx:8009 in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I have done so far, which make it happen.
Service can be accesed at:

```
  http://47.168.96.31/StockQuote/StockQuoteService
```

Installation:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apacheHttpServer3 --enable-modules=proxy
```

Configuration:

```
<Proxy balancer://kekagent>
      BalancerMember http://47.168.96.31:2020  loadfactor=10
      BalancerMember http://192.168.0.2:2020   loadfactor=10 timeout=2
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /StockQuote/StockQuoteService balancer://kekagent/StockQuote/StockQuoteService
```